# how to change color and add text to an image

Tags: css, ajax, jquery-ui

hello i want to make a website i want for the users to pick a color blue white and black without reloading the page. when the user picks a color then he has the option of adding text on top of the color image and also has the option of adding an image. i want to sell shirts where the customer can pick and choose a color of the shirt then he or she can add a text and or image like custom ink does when u want to order a shirt. i would like to use jquery if its possible. i have not tried anything because i dont know where to start iam new to coding

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question however is off topic on stack overflow as we are a Q&A site for answering inquiries on specific programming bugs and problems. General design questions and **Please write my code for me** are off topic. Please take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic] to see information in regards to what is both on topic for SO, and if you can revise your question to meet these requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new you should look into the basics of jQuery. This could help you:
[First steps jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)
Also.. if you want to change backgrounds or general css you can look at:
[jQuery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [jQuery addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)